# Read from console with C#, split and write into 2 lists w/o saving to string

Tags: c#, .net

I have the following code, which works:

```
class p003
{
    static void Main()
    {
        int intBorder = 1900;
        int intN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int>listPoints = new List<int>();
        List<int> listRanks = new List<int>();
        string strRead;

        for (int i = 0; i < intN ; i++)
        {
            strRead = Console.ReadLine();
            listPoints.Add(int.Parse(strRead.Split()[0]));
            listRanks.Add(int.Parse(strRead.Split()[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

The input looks like this:

```
2
1 21
2 -32
```

**My question** is whether it is possible at all to write the values, entered in the console without recording them as a string first. (this is what strRead does). Thus, in the for loop I would like to eliminate strRead, but somehow directly from Console.Readline() to divide the string into two parts and to write them on the lists.

Something like this:

```
listPoints.add(int.Parse(console.Readline().split[0]));
listRanks.add(int.Parse(console.Readline().split[1]));
```

It will not work, because I would read twice from the console and hence the values would be different.

Comment: That's the only way to do it, otherwise you're not giving the input a `Type` and it could cause a runtime exception, and also there's no other API to simply regurgitate what the input is without allocating memory for it.

Comment: Why would you want to eliminate saving the input to a string?

Comment: Well, I was thinking of something fancier. Simply thought that there should be some other way and I have decided to ask.

Comment: You could `string[] strRead = Console.ReadLine().Split();` so you dont have to split twice.

Comment: @TobiasR. thanks.I am trying to avoid the intermediate. I thought that there can be something like the Python `k,n = n,k`, but with a `console.readline()` somewhere.

Comment: You could also get the stream of the console and get one char after the other and add them immediatly to your lists. that way you dont have to save them as a string first.. but it would me much more complicated in the end

Comment: @TobiasR.The input can be with 2 or 3 digits as well.

Comment: @Vityata thats why it would be too complicated in the end :P

Comment: Instead of capturing the `string` I'd call `Split` on it and capture the array to use `var input  = Console.ReadLine().Split();`.  You could even make it a one liner if you use Linq `listPoints.AddRange(Console.ReadLine().Split().Select(int.Parse).Take(2));` thought that does not guarantee that they entered at least two values (your code throws an exception if they don't).

Comment: @juharr - the one liner seems really nice, but how can I use it for both lists?

Comment: @Vityata Never mind I misread that as adding to the same list.  The best bet is to just capture the array from `Split` instead.

Comment: Ok. But capturing the array from split is pretty much like writing it to a string, e.g. we get an intermediate value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use `Console.ReadLine()` inside a `foreach` loop and then interact with the characters.

Here is my code, you can then add to one or another list based on a condition.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            List<int>listPoints = new List<int>();
            List<int> listRanks = new List<int>();

            for (int i = 0; i < 1; i++)
            {
                Console.ReadLine()
                    .Split()
                    .ToList()
                    .ForEach(s => {
                        listPoints.Add(int.Parse(s));
                        //or
                        listRanks.Add(int.Parse(s));
                    });

                foreach(string numero in Console.ReadLine().Split()) {
                    listPoints.Add(int.Parse(numero));
                    //or
                    listRanks.Add(int.Parse(numero));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I removed some things from your code just for test.

Comment: This is not functionally equivalent to OPs code, and hardly more readable. What's the deal with `//or`?

Comment: `Console.ReadLine` is already a `string`, so there's not point in calling `ToString` after it.

Comment: So I should either use the `for` or `foreach`? Both seem interesting :)

Comment: Yes, I guess, but in either ways you would be creating a variable inside the scope (a counter on the`for` loop and the `string` inside the `foreach`), and some another to decide whether `List` to add

Answer (score 1):

Another try

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int intBorder = 1900;
        int intN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());

        for (int i = 0; i < intBorder; i++)
        {
            Storer.Store(Console.ReadLine().Split());
        }
    }

    static class Storer
    {
        public static readonly List<int> listPoints = new List<int>();
        public static readonly List<int> listRanks = new List<int>();

        public static void Store(string[]data)
        {
            listPoints.Add(int.Parse(data[0]));
            listRanks.Add(int.Parse(data[1]));
        }
    }
}
```

The Storer type has the both collections

Comment: That's something interesting :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is another way to save a few characters:

```
using System.Linq;
using a=System.Console;
using b=System.Collections.Generic.List<int>;
using c=System.Int32;
using d=System.String;

namespace e
{
    class f
    {
        static d x=>a.ReadLine();
        static c _(d f)=>c.Parse(f);
        static d[] g(d f)=>f.Split();

        static void Main()
        {
            var n=_(x);var p=new b();var r=p.ToList();var i=1^1;
            while(n-->0)g(x).ToList().ForEach(v=>((i++%2==0)?p:r).Add(_(v)));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Wow! I did not know the way of declaring like this -> `using a=System.Console;` :)

Comment: @Vityata: yeah, well it's a joke answer, this would hardly help with readability. :) The only thing that makes sense noticing is the `(i++%2==0)?p:r` part, which seems to be missing in Gustavo's answer; i.e. add the first item to the first list, and the second one to the second list.

Comment: Well, if we consider readability, obviously my working code in the question is the best one, but not what I needed. :)

Answer (score 0):

You could do

```
int intBorder = 1900;
        int intN = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        List<int> listPoints = new List<int>();
        List<int> listRanks = new List<int>();

        for (int i = 0; i < intBorder; i++)
        {
            listPoints.Add(int.Parse(""+Console.ReadKey().KeyChar));
            listRanks.Add(int.Parse("" + Console.ReadKey().KeyChar));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Obviusly this is not considering error handling

Hope it helps!

Comment: Thanks, but the input can be with 2 or 3 digits as well.